# facebook unable to load/work properly in linux

Tags: internet, vpn

I'm connected to a VPN and I am experiencing some issues accessing various websites (including Facebook, Amazon and YouTube, as examples). In Ubuntu everything works fine if I disable the VPN, but I want to use it. In Windows 7 everything is working with the same VPN connection. Why not in Ubuntu?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 32 bit machine with Mozilla Firefox 40.0.3 but I have also tested using the Opera browser and the problem remains same.

Here are some typical scenarios I'm experiencing:

- After login, the first page appears is not loading fully to see more stories.
- chat window is not appearing
- Any picture is not opening on clicking over it.
- Whenever I click on like button, it does not work.

I also tried to upload a profile picture to Ask Ubuntu but that didn't work either.

Can anybody tell me what is going on?

Comment: refer [here](http://www.techchore.com/facebook-not-loading-properly/)

Comment: Ya, thank you for the fast response. I saw that side as well within my google "research", but the mentioned solution didn't help...

Comment: Have you tried to restart browser after connecting to VPN?

Comment: My only thought is that Windows may configure the VPN automatically, while Linux you may have to do it manually

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out the solution to this problem together with technical support.

You have to change the connection protocol from UDP to TCP and set the port from 9120 to 80. That did the trick for me. Now everything runs smoth and I have no further errors.

I hope this help you guys out.